# Defines height/width based on the window height/width Jquery

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

How can i define the With and Height of an image based on the window width and height?

I tried somethings like set the variables:

```
    var w_width = $(window).width();  
    var w_weight = $(window).height();  
    var display_x = $('.display img').width();  
    var display_y = $('.display img').height();
```

and, after, set the conditions:

```
    if (displayx == wwidth) {
        $(displayx).css('max-width',90%);
    } else if (displayy == wheight) {
        $(displayy).css('max-height',90%);
    } else {
        $(displayy).css('max-height',90%);
    }
```

But, in addition to it not function, i have no idea from where to start.

I would like to put these code in this webpage, to preserve it responsive with the display (click in one image to see the image display).

Have someone any idea about it?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height -- please read the documentation for those methods, you can use them as both setters and getters.

Comment: Start by using the same names for the variables, and what are the odds the image is exactly the same size as the window, and your variables are **not** elements, they are just numbers, read the link from Blazemonger above ??

Comment: What i want to do is adjust the image inside the browser, maintaining the proportion and don't let the image bigger than browser, in width or height. I tried to do this, but i have no idea for where begin...